# Python: do not exclude rows after map(dictionary)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to use a dictionary in order to create a new field/column in a dataframe. If the values don't match, I want the value to be set to 'NA' or something similar.

So, I am using something like this:

```
#Creation of a dictionary after combining two lists
country_Codes = ['us', 'de', 'fr']
values        = ['US', 'EU', 'EU']
dictionary = dict(zip(country_Codes, values))

df['new'] = df['Country_Code'].map(dictionary, na_action=None)
```

and it creates the new column normally when I export everything to a CSV. The problem is that it skips the non-matched rows. My script excludes some rows if there is no match from the dictionary. I thought the issue was related to this line: 
`na_action='ignore'`

Here is an example code I used in jupyter where I created temporarily the s and d series:

```
s = pd.Series(['us', 'de', 'random1','random2', 'fr', 'random3'])
d = pd.Series(['us', 'de', 'random1','random2', 'fr', 'random3'])

#Creation of a dictionary after combining two lists
country_Codes = ['us', 'de', 'fr']
values        = ['US', 'EU', 'EU']
dictionary = dict(zip(country_Codes, values))

a = s.map(dictionary, na_action=None)
b = d.map(dictionary, na_action='ignore')
```

and this is what I can see after printing:

[image]

My first question is how do I see the same results? It seems as if the `na_action` does not apply. Secondly, how can I keep the rows in a more complex dataframe with multiple columns? I checked that the type is correct after printing the `type()`:

> class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'

Is there a way to keep the rows after there is no match for this field (`Country_Code`) with the dictionary values?

Also, is there a way to print the rows where the field (`Country_Code`) does not have a match with the dictionary values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several questions here:

(1) `na_action`

`na_action` relates to the input not the output. Here is an example lifted from `pandas` documentation:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan])
>>> s2 = s.map('this is a string {}'.format, na_action=None)
0    this is a string 1.0
1    this is a string 2.0
2    this is a string 3.0
3    this is a string nan
dtype: object

>>> s3 = s.map('this is a string {}'.format, na_action='ignore')
0    this is a string 1.0
1    this is a string 2.0
2    this is a string 3.0
3                     NaN
dtype: object
```

(2) How to keep rows if no match?

This may be what you are looking for. If it can't find a match, it won't change.

```
b = d.replace(dictionary)
```

(3) Print rows where `Country_Code` does not have a match in dictionary.

```
df[~df['Country_Code'].isin(dictionary)]
```

Comment: The second line works fine. I think the lambda is slightly better in this case. The last row does not work. It returns all the rows.

Comment: What do you see for `df['Country_Code'].isin(dictionary)` ? This should be a Boolean array with some `False` values provided there are Country_Code values not in your dictionary keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) regarding the difference.

As for the desired result I suggest [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply):

```
a = s.apply(lambda x: dictionary[x] if x in dictionary else x)
```

Comment: Sorry, have to downvote this. Isn't this the purpose of the inbuilt `pd.Series.replace` ?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis You don't have to downvote, yet you did. You are correct it does the job, but are you saying that this is not correct solution?

Comment: I don't downvote lightly, remember it costs me too :). I downvote not only when the solution is incorrect, but also when it propagates bad practice. Sometimes "bad practice" is subjective and I hold off, but this is more clear-cut.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis It worked fine for me. So, did your example. I am just trying to find a way to present the unmatched from the dictionary. The third row you gave does not return the unmatched rows. It returns the whole dataframe.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer, SO, in my opinion, works better as a learning tool. Not a "fix it, it works!" paradigm. This applies to both askers and responders.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis How is this going to work`df[~df['Country_Code'].isin(dictionary)]`? I believe the dictionary should be replace with the values (that are used in the dictionary. It works if I add a list there. Is that right?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer, run this code obviously before your perform the `replace`.

Comment: @zipa No need to downvote anything. it is not a high level contest. It worked fine.

Comment: I didn't downvote anything. Only @jp_data_analysis downvoted this answer