# Ideas for extracting string when its place varies from row to row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to extract a string(username) from a excel table.

username's place varies from row to row for example:

- D:\Users\james
- D:\Users\johnny2
- D:\Userdata\Users\mark\My Documents
- D:\Users\Jessica\My Private Files\Files
- D:\NewteamUsers\Molly2\Documents

What I need to extract is only usernames

- james
- johnny2
- mark
- Jessica
- Molly2

Because it varies from row to row I can't use a function to extract after nth character or specific character. Only common things are before usernames start always there is "sers\" and "\" character or blank space.

Could you please guide me how can I implement this using functions?

Comment: use a regular expression that extracts the first part after "Users\".  Like "Users\\([^\]*)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A2, 1, FIND("sers\", A2)+4, TEXT(,))&"\", "\", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)))
```

If *Users* is not always proper case, swap SEARCH for FIND and you will get a non-case-sensitive location for the string search.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This one should work:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("\",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("Users\",A1)-5))),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("Users\",A1)-5),LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("Users\",A1)-5),FIND("\",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("Users\",A1)-5))-1))
```

Comment: @jezrael The other guy did it most probably. He downvotes me almost each time we both propose an answer, once arguing I'm [_promoting bad practices_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519894/python-do-not-exclude-rows-after-mapdictionary/48520028#48520028) :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more approach.

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\",REPT(" ",99)),SEARCH("sers",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\",REPT(" ",99)),1)+99,99))`